# how to modify the default capacity instance blockDevice for EKS using CDK?

Tags: amazon-eks, aws-cdk

I am running a cluster with a couple of nodes.
I logged in to a node and found 90% of disk space usage.

```
[root@ip-10-100-2-137 /]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           7.9G  2.6M  7.9G   1% /run
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvda1       20G   18G  2.0G  90% /
```

My cdk script looks like this:

```js
export class DevK8SClusterStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const vpc = Vpc.fromLookup(this, 'vpc', {
      vpcName: 'vpc'
    })

    const allowSshSG = new SecurityGroup(this, 'allow-ssh', {
      vpc, securityGroupName: 'allow-ssh',
      allowAllOutbound: true
    })
    allowSshSG.addIngressRule(Peer.anyIpv4(), Port.tcp(22), 'allow ssh')

    const cluster = new Cluster(this, 'cluster', {
      version: KubernetesVersion.V1_21,
      vpc,
      defaultCapacity: 2,
      defaultCapacityType: DefaultCapacityType.EC2,
      defaultCapacityInstance: InstanceType.of(InstanceClass.T2, InstanceSize.XLARGE)
    })

    cluster.defaultCapacity?.role.addManagedPolicy(ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore'))
    cluster.defaultCapacity?.addSecurityGroup(allowSshSG)

  }
}
```

Is there a way to increase the default capacity instance Block Device for EKS using CDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_eks-readme.html#managed-node-groups): *Additional customizations are available post instantiation. To apply them, set the default capacity to 0, and use the `cluster.addNodegroupCapacity` method.*  The [NodeGroup diskSize](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_eks.Nodegroup.html#disksize) can be set in that way:

```js
const cluster = new eks.Cluster(this, 'cluster', {
  version: eks.KubernetesVersion.V1_21,
  defaultCapacity: 0,
});

cluster.addNodegroupCapacity('custom-node-group', {
  instanceTypes: [ec2.InstanceType.of(ec2.InstanceClass.T2, ec2.InstanceSize.XLARGE)],
  minSize: 2,
  diskSize: 100,
});
```